# Linux Access Denied issue on Windows files

Tags: linux, windows, permissions

My primary OS is Linux (Fedora 28 to be specific), but I keep a VM box of Windows 10 handy incase I ever need it, I haven't for awhile but I found a game that has to be downloaded from the Windows Store that I wanted to try and get working in WINE. Alot of other "Windows Only" games have been running better and better in WINE since DXVK entered the scene, including new triple-A titles, so I figured it'd be worth a shot. 
But I'm running into an odd issue with this.
I keep alot of my games on an NTFS partition that both Windows and Linux can have read/write access to, for simplicity. (I use to dual-boot, having access to those games on both OS' just made my life simpler), some of those games were downloaded while on Windows, but I have permissions to access and modify those files when on Linux, however for this specific game, I can't seem to get Linux to be able to access the files at all. Even root is coming up with Access Denied issues, and I'm not sure why.

I've never downloaded an app from the windows store and tried to run it on Linux before now, is this just some kind of DRM protection issue I'm encountering, or is there some special trick to getting access to these files?

Comment: Does syslog say something? What are the complete mount options?

Comment: It's mounted during boot with fstab, but I also tried a simple  mount --rw /dev/sdb1 /run/media/user and have the same problem.  I have access to other files on the drive just fine.

fstab entry: UUID=6A20BDF120BDC47B /run/media/Joker/Games auto defaults 0 0

Comment: 1) Which NTFS driver are you using, ntfs-3g or the built-in kernel driver? 2) What specific files are you trying to access? 3) _How_ specifically are you trying to access them? What action gives this error message? 4) What do the files or folders look like under `ls -ld`?

Comment: I'm 99% certain the Fedora kernel uses ntfs-3g but I've tried with both mount and ntfs-3g commands to mount the drive. Specifically, the files downloaded for Sea of Thieves by the Windows store.    Any form of accessing them, i've tried running the games .exe through WINE, aswell as just viewing config/settings files with gedit, nano and pluma, even using root to try and view the text files says permission denied

Comment: ls -ld on the /run/media/user/Games folder, drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 32768 Jan  7 03:30 
ls -ld on the /run/media/user/Games/WindowsApp/Microsoft.SeaofThieves folder, drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4096 Jan  7 02:36 .

Comment: Under Windows, you could run `chkdsk` to check the disk integrity.

Comment: I think I've found the problem, under windows, things in the WindowsApps folder appear to be encrypted for some reason. No matter what I do, even my administrator account on Windows cannot directly access the files without going through the Windows Store

Comment: Still haven't had any luck with this, any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I usually get that kind of error when I launch windows and then I acidentally turn off the machine without correctly shutting down using start menu. I suggest you boot into Windows first and then try to access your Windows files again in Linux.

Comment: This is a different issue than that. The issue you're talking about usually affects the entire partition, not specific files. It's because of how Windows closes (or doesn't) it's access to NTFS partitions when it shuts down, forcing the partition into a read-only mode until the issue is resolved. (either by starting windows and doing a proper shutdown, or with the ntfsfix command. The partition itself is fine, and other files created by Windows on the VM are accessible fine.)

Comment: Did you try a tool to change all permissions? (https://www.top-password.com/take-ownership-pro.html) Or maybe setting permissions to Everyone instead of only one user?

Comment: I have tried both of those, no change